# EditText.getText() returning empty string where EditText is not empty; it is set by android:hint="Enter Bus Number"

Tags: android

I have 3 EditTexts. I am checking 1 of them named text. But I am not able to retrieve its value through getText(). It seems to be returning empty string. I stored text.getText.tostring into String Command. Then copied Command into Command2. Then try to set the contents of HTTPResult EditText using setText. But it is empty. I am so much confused.
CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="fill_vertical" android:layout_margin="10dp">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:lines="1"

        android:hint="Enter Bus Number">

    </EditText>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Bus_number"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:lines="1"
        android:hint="Bus Number is:">

    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_Connect"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Register new bus" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/HTTPResult"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:lines="10"
        android:hint="Waiting for Result ...">

    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn_Connect ;
    EditText busNumberEdit;
    EditText text1;
    EditText HTTPResult;
    String busNumber;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn_Connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_Connect);
        busNumberEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Bus_number);
        text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
        HTTPResult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.HTTPResult);
        String Command = (String) text1.getText().toString();
        String Command2 = Command;
        HTTPResult.setText(Command2);
        String stop = (String) busNumberEdit.getText().toString();
        if(Command.compareTo("Enter Bus Number") == 0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You download is resumed2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            busNumber = (String) busNumberEdit.getText().toString();
            //MyTaskParams paramObj = new MyTaskParams(3, myServer, busNumber, Command2, "");
            //paramObj.print();
            //HTTPResult.setText(Command2);
            //conn.execute(paramObj);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you filling your `EditText`, what do you mean in your question title **"it is set by android:hint"** ?

Comment: `hint` and `text` are two different properties of `edittext`, `hint` will the user what to enter in that `edittext` whereas `text` is the property that will hold the text entered to editext by the user or set by `android:text` property or by `setText()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need to get the string "Enter Bus Number" as the value filled in your `text1` EditText, you need to set text of the EditText in your xml with the attribute `android:text`, like follows:

```
...

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:lines="1"

        android:text="Enter Bus Number">

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `editText.getText()` to retrieve a hint. For that you need `editText.getHint()`. I am not sure what you want to achieve here because `.getText()` will retrieve anything that is added in `android:text` field in XML, `editText.setText()` programmatically or by user input.

I am looking at your code and I want to understand what you are doing but I can't completely. Let's take it slow.

If `EditText` doesn't have the text and only has a hint, this line will return an empty `String`:

```
String Command = (String) text1.getText().toString();
```

When you compare `String` to another `String` or like you did ("Enter bus number"), you should use `string.contentEquals(anotherString)`. This way you can compare the content of two variables which don't need to be `String`, it can also be `CharSequence`, `StringBuilder`, etc. So using `.compareTo()` should be changed.

In this line of your code:

```
 if(Command.compareTo("Enter Bus Number") == 0)
```

there you should use it like this:

```
if(Command.contentEquals("Enter bus Number")) {
```

then proceed below in your code. This will return true if Command is equal to the `String` you provided. But this isn't a way to go with this. Are you trying to check if Command is actually empty? Do you want to check if the user didn't write anything? Then you can use `TextUtils`:

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Command)) {
```

or

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString())) {
```

This will return `TRUE` if editText is empty and the user didn't input any value in it.